# Feedback content for the request's response

Tags: feedback, content, user-feedback

Let's say I have a 'variables' form, the user is supposed to `add a new variable` or `save an existing variable`.

I have made a feedback component which includes an icon, title, and a message.

when the user submits the form (clicked save), I have composed the following feedback on success after adding a new variable:

```
Variable Added Successfully
For the list of added variables go to My Variables 
Go Back
```

It is titled "Success", with a checked arrow.

The question is, What can I improve in that content or replace for better readability.

Comment: Hey Ali, I do understand HTML as some of the other contributors but, you should better share the visual outlook if you want to get more addressing answer. Otherwise it mightl be flagged or stay unanswered since it contains implementation rather than experience's itself.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the possibilities to improve:

1. Go Back -> Transform into icon or "x" in the specific place.
2. Presented Visually (green for confirm, yellow for warning, red for error) eg:
   [image]
3. Adding interpunction.
4. Condensed and personalize text eg: - "Success! View list of added variable."

Answer (score 0):

You could cut down on the amount of words, potentially decreasing cognitive load in the process while increasing readability. E.g.:

"For the list of added variables go to My Variables" could be reworded as "Review My Variables" (i.e. short and sweet).